# Tail recursive way to sort and merge two lists

Tags: list, haskell

I'm trying to write a tail recursive way to merge two sorted lists into a single sorted list.

Here is what I have. First I have non tail recursive way

```
merge2 :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge2 l1 [] = l1
merge2 [] l2 = l2
merge2 (x:xs) (y:ys) | x > y = y : merge2 (x:xs) ys
                     | x < y = x : merge2 xs (y:ys)
                     | otherwise = x : merge2 (x:xs) ys

mergeTail :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
mergeTail accum [] = accum
mergeTail accum (x:xs) = mergeTail (x:accum) xs
```

When I input something like merge2Tail [1,2] [2,3,4] I expect to get [1,2,2,3,4] as the output but instead I get it in some random order. I'm not sure where or how to implement a case for checking order while keeping it tail recursive.

Comment: Do you know how to do it in a non-tail-recursive way?

Comment: Yes, should I edit this and include it?

Comment: That sounds rather inefficient. Why do you want it to be tail recursive?

Comment: @Larry.Fish: Yes, you should. :)

Comment: I am doing this for a homework assignment

Comment: @Larry.Fish You want three arguments then, `l1` and `l2` and the accumulator.

Comment: Wouldn't that require 3 arguments passed in when I call it? What would I pass in as the third?

Comment: Yes, an accumulator-based solution uses a helper function with an additional argument. Initially, it can be an empty list. While recursing, prepend the element you wish to "output" to the accumulator. At the very end, the accumulator will contain the wanted list, in reversed order.

Comment: One of the following two things is almost certainly a bad sign: 1. `mergeTail` does not call `merge2` anywhere, OR 2. `mergeTail` does not call `(>)` anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

As others have noted, this is a highly artificial exercise: merging two sorted lists to form one sorted list should *not* be done tail recursively in Haskell. But if you were building a *strict-spined* list in a language environment with a very limited call stack size and no support for tail recursion modulo cons, this could be a reasonable thing to do. In such an environment, it's usually best to divide problems like this into two parts:

1. Walk through the list(s), building a list in reverse as an accumulator.
2. Build the final result using the accumulator.

Let's start with that.

```
merge :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge = \xs ys -> go [] xs ys
  where
    go acc [] ys = reverse acc ++ ys
    go acc xs [] = reverse acc ++ xs
    go acc xss@(x : xs) yss@(y : ys)
      | x <= y = go (x : acc) xs yss
      | otherwise = go (y : acc) xss ys
```

There's an efficiency problem (even under the conditions described above): `reverse` completely rebuilds its argument, and `++` completely rebuilds its *first* argument. So `reverse acc ++ ys` rebuilds `acc` twice (if `++` were also written tail-recursively, it would be rebuilt *three times*). Let's fix that.

```
-- reverseOnto xs ys = reverse xs ++ ys
reverseOnto :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
reverseOnto [] ys = ys
reverseOnto (x : xs) ys = reverseOnto xs (x : ys)
```

Finally,

```
merge :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge = \xs ys -> go [] xs ys
  where
    go acc [] ys = acc `reverseOnto` ys
    go acc xs [] = acc `reverseOnto` xs
    go acc xss@(x : xs) yss@(y : ys)
      | x <= y = go (x : acc) xs yss
      | otherwise = go (y : acc) xss ys
```

I believe that's about the best you can do under your constraints.

Comment: BTW `reverseOnto` is so common a paradigm to use in Lisps, I always thought there's  even a built-in for that, `revappend` or something; or should be, if there isn't. (or of course we can do `flip $ foldl' (flip (:))` in Haskell). :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, let's see how a non-tail-recursive looks like:

```
merge :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge xs []                                 = xs
merge [] ys                                 = ys
merge fullXs@(x:xs) fullYs@(y:ys)  | x <= y = x : merge xs fullYs
                                   | x > y  = y : merge fullXs ys
```

To make it tail recursion, you must have an `accum` somewhere, and call a sub function helper.
 As it is tail recursive, you must add the element at the end in order to maintain the order:

See what happens with `foldl` :

```
foldl (flip (:)) [] [1,2,3,4,5]
=> [5,4,3,2,1]
```

So the function will be:

```
mergeTail :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
mergeTail xs [] = xs
mergeTail [] ys = ys
mergeTail xs ys = mergeAccum [] xs ys


mergeAccum :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
mergeAccum acc [] []                       = acc
mergeAccum acc [] (y:ys)                   = mergeAccum (acc ++ [y]) [] ys
mergeAccum acc (x:xs) []                   = mergeAccum (acc ++ [x]) xs []
mergeAccum acc (x:xs) (y:ys)  | x <= y     = mergeAccum (acc ++ [x]) xs (y:ys)
                              | x > y      = mergeAccum (acc ++ [y]) (x:xs) ys
```

ejemplo:

```
$> mergeTail [1,2,6] [1,2,3,5]
=> [1,1,2,2,3,5,6]
```

> Note:

In this case this function is inefficient because it has to go to the end of the `accum` list every each recursive call.

Comment: the standard remedy for such cases is to build the accumulator in reverse, with the *efficient* `(:)`, and reverse the accumulated result in the base case before returning.

Comment: @WillNess I don't quite understand your concept, how it should be? I didn't know it

Comment: you change `mergeAccum (acc ++ [y]) ...` in the recursive clauses into `mergeAccum (y : acc) ...` and you change the base case clause `... = acc` into `... = reverse acc`. :)